# Why only the last value that we are trying to add is stored in an arraylist repeatedly

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am retrieving each and every value of a single record and copying it into another array variable and setting array using a bean class and then adding that bean class to an arraylist.While I am trying to print it shows only the last record repeatedly

```
try{
    st=con.createStatement();
    rs=st.executeQuery("select * from data");
    while(rs.next()){
        DataBean db=new DataBean();
        for(int i=1;i<=tNumber;i++){
            a[i]=rs.getFloat(i);
        }
        db.setArray(a);
        al.add(db);
   }
} finally {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Please post some code, your result depends on what you actually wrote, not what you tried to do.

Comment: Post your code, so we can help you better

Comment: because you have not posted your code..

Comment: try{
   st=con.createStatement();
   rs=st.executeQuery("select * from data");

   while(rs.next()){
    DataBean db=new DataBean();
    
    for(int i=1;i<=tNumber;i++){
     a[i]=rs.getFloat(i);
    }
                db.setArray(a);
                
                 al.add(db);
}

Comment: Where is the array `a` coming from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last entry is stored in the array repeatedly because you are storing the same object multiple times. This is a very common error - it happens when you write code that looks like this:

```
MyObject obj = new MyObject();
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
while (haveMoreEntries()) {
    obj.setName(readName());
    obj.setAddress(readAddress());
    list.add(obj);
}
```

The problem with the code above is that it keeps adding the same object repeatedly. The fix is to move the call of the constructor into the loop, like this:

```
List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
while (haveMoreEntries()) {
    MyObject obj = new MyObject();
    obj.setName(readName());
    obj.setAddress(readAddress());
    list.add(obj);
}
```

In your case, the problem is the shared array `a`: you created it once, and then you call `db.setArray(a);` repeatedly. You should move the creation of `a` into the `while` loop, or better yet, change `db.setArray` to make a copy of the array.

Comment: If i have created it once and repeatedly calling then is there any other alternative to do that

Comment: @user3534517 Change `db.setArray` to make a copy of the array that you pass, rather than storing the array: inside `setArray` make a new array of floats, and copy the items from the array that you pass in.

Answer (score 0):

The bean object has to be local. I guess in your case you would have made it global which is creating the problem.